# Android: Get data insert in custom listview

Tags: android, listview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Nyo.png)

I want to display the user on the custom listview, each line listview has 2 textview and social network url, when click on the listview will lead to social networking site. I tried but failed, can you suggest me? Thank you very much.

Comment: Before asking here use google first refer: [here](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First take a list_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#dedbdc"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- User Name-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rama"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <!-- age -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/age"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/userName"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:text="Just gona stand there and ..." />

    <!-- Rightend info -->
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

DataModel.java

```
public class DataModel {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String website;

    public DataModel(String name, String age, String website) {
      this.name = name;
      this.age = age;
      this.website = website;
   }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataModel> {

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtAge;
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data, Context context) {
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    private int lastPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        DataModel dataModel = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            viewHolder.txtAge = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.age);

            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }
        lastPosition = position;

        viewHolder.txtName.setText(dataModel.getName());
        viewHolder.txtAge.setText(dataModel.getAge());

        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import com.geeklabs.rssprarthana.DataModel;
import com.geeklabs.rssprarthana.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<DataModel> dataModels;
    ListView listView;
    private static CustomAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        dataModels= new ArrayList<>();

        // TO DO add your list data here for example
        dataModels.add(new DataModel("Shylendra", "25","http://facebook.com"));

        adapter= new CustomAdapter(dataModels,getApplicationContext());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                DataModel dataModel= dataModels.get(position);

                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(dataModel.getWebsite()));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Glad to help you.. :) Happy coding